# I have 2 identical windows 2008 r2 servers with 32G RAM, one shows "Installed Memory(Ram): 32.0GB" and the other shows "Installed Memory(Ram): 32.0GB (28.0GB usable)" ?

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory, hp-proliant

the server model:
HP Poliant DL160 G5, both servers have identical product ID.

for some reason one of the servers have 4GB ram reserved. it shows in the memory tab on the Resource monitor as "Hardware Reserved". 
I've googled it a bit and found some post related to msconfig boot parameters (but mine are properly set) and some post related to memory remap option in the bios but it is not available in my servers bios so in a bit lost... help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do a memtest on the memory- is probably a faulty module. Could be the gfx card taking some of the memory (less likely).

Comment: If it was faulty it wouldn't even be visible to the O.S., would it?

Comment: It could actually, I've seen it before. In the Windows 7 article for similar problem it lists physical memory problems as a potential cause for this issue. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978610

Comment: I wonder also if the placement of the RAM on the motherboard might be an issue- is this identical on both servers?

Answer (score 1):

Do the two servers have the same BIOS releases?

Do they have identical hardware configuration (including optional boards, components, etc.)?

Have you tried resetting the BIOS on both servers to factory defaults?